# ngdatepicker works in Chrome, but doesn't work in IE11

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, datepicker

So, I am using a very simple `ngDatepicker`. It works fine in Firefox and Chrome. But not at all in IE. Here is my code. I stripped it down so that this page has nothing but the datepicker on it, but still doesn't work.

```js
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />

<div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input class="form-control" placeholder="From" id="datefromformat" [minDate]="minDate" [maxDate]="maxDate"
        formControlName="datefromformat" [(ngModel)]="datefromformat" ngbDatepicker #dp="ngbDatepicker" readonly>
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" id="controlName" (click)="onClick($event)" type="button">
          <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="date.get('datefromformat').touched && date.get('datefromformat').invalid" class="alert-danger">
      <div *ngIf="date.get('datefromformat').hasError('patternValidator')">
        Date should be in the format of MM/DD/YYYY
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="date.get('datefromformat').hasError('lengthValidator')">
        Date should be in the format of MM/DD/YYYY
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="date < maxDate && date > minDate">
        Date should be in the range.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas on how to fix the issue?

Comment: can you add your code in stackblitz.com